# Flatlist data is lost when changing screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I have a screen that displays a Flatlist with some data in it, but when I go back to the previous screen and come back back to this acreen with the Flatlist, the data is not more there. I use React Navigation to move between screens and also to move data.

This is the code I use to go back:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the data to put in the Flatlist? Is it in `this.state`?

Comment: Yes I get the data from `this.state`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are on the first page, only that page is mounted. Then you go to page2 with the Flatlist. Now both page1 and page2 are mounted.

When you use `navigation.goBack()`, page2 is unmounted. This means `this.state` on page2 is deleted.

So now when you go to page2 for the second time, it is re-mounted (so a new/empty state is used)

If you want to preserve the state between mount/unmount/re-mount, you will either need a state management tool, or pass all data via the navigator.

Comment: Is there anyway I can fix that?

Comment: it will depend on your project. External state management (like Redux) is an option, however, it is probably overkill for this case.